# Number Keypad for iPad in React Native

Tags: ios, react-native, ipad, ios-simulator, numeric-keypad

I'm developing an iPad application in React Native in which I want to show number only keypad. I have used keyboard type as phone-pad but is shows numbers alongwith extra characters. How should I achieve that? How should I use the Custom keypad in react native for iOS.

Comment: If you are using `TextInput` from react-native, you can choose `keyboardType`. Here's a visual guide for different `keyboardType`s https://lefkowitz.me/visual-guide-to-react-native-textinput-keyboardtype-options/. `numeric` will give you a number only keypad which is available for both ios and android.

Answer (score 2):

I am attaching a below screenshot for how many keyboard type you can show along with their respective `keywords`.

for your case just add

> keyboardType="number-pad"

if you are using TextInput for your keyboard

[image]

Update: for iPad either you need a custom keyboad which can only contains number only or what you can do is:

**Simply remove the the text from number input even if the keyboard has characters**

You can do this way

```
`<TextInput 
    placeHolder="*********"
    keyboardType="number-pad"
    onChangeText={this.onChangeText.bind(this)}
    value={text}
 />` 

`onChangeText(text) {
    const numbers = '0123456789';
    let numberOnly = '';

    for (let i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
        if (numbers.indexOf(text[i]) > -1) {
            numberOnly += text[i];
        }
    }
   this.props.passwordChanged(numberOnly); }
```

Comment: Does this really work? I tested with iPad 13.4.1, though keyboard switch to "numeric" (where user still able to switch back to alphabet)... I was expecting something like https://lefkowitz.me/visual-guide-to-react-native-textinput-keyboardtype-options/.... Also I found out, from Apple site it seems they do support iPad numeric only keyboard. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205374

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `keyboardType="number-pad"`. This solution works on both iOS and Android.

Comment: @RoshanSinghBisht Thanks for the Answer, but you are restricting the characters in the textfield with numbers. But my query is I want to display only number keypad in iPad.

Comment: @AmitShetye then you need a custom keypad, like this one. https://github.com/reactnativecn/react-native-custom-keyboard